Is the weak topology on the infinite-dimensional separable Hilbert space Hereditarily Lindelöf?
This question is about the Weak topology on a separable Hilbert space and has arisen after having read the following question: Is the weak topology on the infinite-dimensional separable Hilbert space $T_5$
?, which has remained unanswered.
I have checked from what other properties of this space is the property $T_4$ deduced:  (see S21|P9). Since $\pi$-Base doesn't know if this space is Hereditarily Lindelöf yet, I have developed an interest in knowing if this space has this property too, because, if it does, it will be consequently deduced that the space verifies a few more separation axioms pending to be determined, including $T_5$.
Perhaps it should be studied directly if this space is $G_{\delta}$. Another approach could be to study if this space has a countable network.

Definition: Let $X$ be a topological space. A family $\mathcal{N}$ of subsets of $X$ is called a network in $X$ if every open set of $X$ is the union of a subfamily of $\mathcal{N}$.
Note: By definition, in a topological space, a base is a network whose elements are open sets.
Lemma: Let $X$ be a set, and let $\tau$, $\tau'$ be two topologies on $X$ such that $\tau' \subseteq \tau$. If $\mathcal{N}$ is a network for $\tau$, then $\mathcal{N}$ is a network for $\tau'$ too.
Proof:
Let $\mathcal{N}$ be a network for $\tau$ and let $A \in \tau'$. As, $A \in \tau' \subseteq \tau$, then $A$ is the union of a subfamily of $\mathcal{N}$. Hence, $\mathcal{N}$ is a network for $\tau'$.

Answering the question:
Let $(X, \tau')$ be the Weak topology on a separable Hilbert space and let $(X, \tau)$ be the Strong topology on a separable Hilbert space.
$(X, \tau)$ is separable and metrizable, so it is second countable. Let $\mathcal{B}$ be a countable base of $(X, \tau)$, $\mathcal{B}$ is a countable network of $(X, \tau)$. As $\tau' \subseteq \tau$, by the Lemma, $\mathcal{B}$ is a countable network of $(X, \tau')$.
Since having a countable network implies hereditarily Lindelöf (see here), $(X, \tau')$ is hereditarily Lindelöf.

Thanks, Patrick!

Yeah! That's what I meant. Thank you so much for the feedback, Patrick.

Very nice explanation!

Thank you so much again, Patrick!
